# How add exceptions to automatic <script> tag linking in sails.js?

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js

I am building an application with Sails.js and using Paper.js library. Paper runs in it's own paperscript scope, which is defined by the type attribute in the script tag. The tag should read

```
<script type="text/paperscript" src="/js/public/prototype.js"></script>
```

In order to work properly. Sails by default links scripts automatically with the grunt-sails linker task and I wasn't able to find any information about how to make exceptions for one file or define a specific type attribute for it. Is there such a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box no. BUT! You can always customize your build pipeline.

Put your `prototype.js` in a new folder called `assets/paperscript`

In `tasks/pipeline.js`, add:

```
var paperFilesToInject = [
  'paperscript/**/*.js'
];

module.exports.paperFilesToInject = paperFilesToInject.map(function(path) {
  return '.tmp/public/' + path;
});
```

In `tasks/config/sails-linker.js`, add the following inside `grunt.config.set('sails-linker', {`:

```
    devPaperscript: {
        options: {
            startTag: '<!--PAPERSCRIPTS-->',
            endTag: '<!--PAPERSCRIPTS END-->',
            fileTmpl: '<script type="text/paperscript" src="%s"></script>',
            appRoot: '.tmp/public'
        },
        files: {
            '.tmp/public/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').paperFilesToInject,
            'views/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').paperFilesToInject,
            'views/**/*.ejs': require('../pipeline').paperFilesToInject
        }
    },

    devPaperscriptRelative: {
        options: {
            startTag: '<!--PAPERSCRIPTS-->',
            endTag: '<!--PAPERSCRIPTS END-->',
            fileTmpl: '<script type="text/paperscript" src="%s"></script>',
            appRoot: '.tmp/public',
            relative: true
        },
        files: {
            '.tmp/public/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').paperFilesToInject,
            'views/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').paperFilesToInject,
            'views/**/*.ejs': require('../pipeline').paperFilesToInject
        }
    },

    prodPaperscript: {
        options: {
            startTag: '<!--PAPERSCRIPTS-->',
            endTag: '<!--PAPERSCRIPTS END-->',
            fileTmpl: '<script type="text/paperscript" src="%s"></script>',
            appRoot: '.tmp/public'
        },
        files: {
            '.tmp/public/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').paperFilesToInject,
            'views/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').paperFilesToInject,
            'views/**/*.ejs': require('../pipeline').paperFilesToInject
        }
    },

    prodPaperscriptRelative: {
        options: {
            startTag: '<!--PAPERSCRIPTS-->',
            endTag: '<!--PAPERSCRIPTS END-->',
            fileTmpl: '<script type="text/paperscript" src="%s"></script>',
            appRoot: '.tmp/public',
            relative: true
        },
        files: {
            '.tmp/public/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').paperFilesToInject,
            'views/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').paperFilesToInject,
            'views/**/*.ejs': require('../pipeline').paperFilesToInject
        }
    },
```

In `tasks/register/linkAssets.js`, add:

```
'sails-linker:devPaperscript',
```

In `tasks/register/linkAssetsBuild.js`, add:

```
'sails-linker:devPaperscriptRelative',
```

In `tasks/register/prod.js`, add:

```
'sails-linker:prodPaperscript',
```

In `tasks/register/linkAssetsProd.js`, add:

```
'sails-linker:prodPaperscriptRelative',
```

In your view, add the following where paperscript should be injected:

```
<!--PAPERSCRIPTS-->
<!--PAPERSCRIPTS END-->
```

Note that, unlike for regular js files, it won't get concat/minified for production.

Comment: One thing you forgot to mention BTW that i feel people may have trouble figuring out is to actually include `paperFilesToInject` variable in the export inside `pipeline.js`. Otherwise `sails-linker.js` can't actually access it through require. Also you need to create tasks in `register/linkAssets.js`.
Also you need to specify a separate tag for it - not <!--SCRIPTS--> but something like <!--PAPER--> or else it will overwrite your normal Javascript.